# Какой тип у выражения с фигурными скобками?

Tags: c++, типы

У литерала `42` тип `int`, у `"42"` - `const char [3]`. А какой тип у чего-то в фигурных скобках? Например, какой тип у `{1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: @Harry но в C же можно его тоже использовать для инициализации массивов, а там нет такого типа.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете о языке C или о C++? У вас метка "с++".

Comment: @Harry о С++, но обычно типы совпадают с С для обратной совместимости.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У него нет типа, и в этом смысле его неправильно называть выражением.

В какой тип его преобразовывать - компилятор понимает из контекста.

Если написать `auto x = {1,2,3}`, то тип определится как `std::initializer_list<int>`, но это не значит, что это "родной" тип скобок. Потому что, например, `template <typename T> void foo(T); foo({1,2,3});` уже не компилируется.

Comment: Если это не выражение, то что?

Comment: @random Просто какая-то запись в коде? Грамматика называет его [*braced-init-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:braced-init-list).